# 'Run function on AWS Lambda' is not coming in Eclipse Project Explorer view, selecting Amazon Web Services

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Java/Maven project. This project has AWS Lambda function code. In Eclipse's Project Explorer view, selecting Amazon Web Services > I don't see 'Run function on AWS Lambda' option. I see only 'Deploy Serverless Project' option.[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6hp1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to right click the handler class, you will see **AWS Lambda** and, select that you can see **Run Lambda**